# Linux command executed from C code system() function giving different result as compared to when executed from Terminal

Tags: c++, bash

I am running a bunch of Linux commands from my C code using system() function. The result of running these commands from C code differs from the result when these commands are run from terminal. Example:

```
std::string name("\\pot\ ");
std::stringstream extractInfoCmd;
extractInfoCmd<<"find . -name \"*.info\" | xargs grep -E \"^PART|^"<<name.c_str()<<"\" >> information.rpt";
std::string extractInfoCmdStr = extractInfoCmd.str();
printf("\n##DEBUG Command: %s\n", extractInfoCmdStr.c_str());
system(extractInfoCmdStr.c_str());
```

If my input file contains these 2 lines:

```
PART: 6
\pot : f
```

Now if I execute the same command(received from DEBUG log above) from terminal, I got both lines. But if I execute the same command from C system() function, I get only first line, not the second line:

```
PART: 6
```

I have been debugging this since long and the cause of it is not striking to me.

Comment: When you launch the terminal and the program, do you start in the same directory? (You are doing a `find`, starting at current directory `.`)

Comment: Have the stream `flush()`ed?

Comment: @Dominique Yes in the same directory

Comment: maybe due to the backslashes which should be escaped because are also escaped in c++ string litteral, also note that backslash followed by space in a c++ string litteral is like a space

Comment: You haven't showed the terminal command. Anyway, I'd try running `strace -f` on both the program and the shell running your terminal pipeline. With the right output/verbosity arguments, it'll show you _exactly_ the command lines run by each, and you can compare them directly.

Comment: I still have not been able to get through with this issue. I have tried it with multiple testcases and the issue still persists. I have tried debugging with strace as well, but am not able to get much out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The backslashes in the `name` string are getting interpreted by your compiler, and then you're using that string to build the `extractInfoCmd` string, which you pass to the shell (`/bin/sh`) which tries to interpret them again. So the actual string that gets passed to the `grep` process isn't the one you intend.

Probably the best way to fix this is to avoid using `system` and instead use something like `execlp`, where you can pass each argument separately.

There's also no need to use a pipeline to pass information from `find` to `grep`, you can do that with `find` itself:

```
find . -name '*.info' -exec grep -E '^PART|^\\pot\ ' {} \;
```

Or, directly in C:

```
execlp(
    "/usr/bin/find",
    ".",
    "-name",
    "*.info",
    "-exec",
    "grep",
    "-E",
    "^PART|^\\\\pot\\ ",
    "{}",
    ";",
    NULL);
```

Rather than piping the output to a file using the shell, you can just use `pipe` in your process to get a pipe to `find`'s standard output directly, which you can then read from.

Comment: furthermore because of double quotes in system string argument backslashes must be double one more time [TIO](https://tio.run/##bZBPC4JAEMXv@ymG7aIHPXawLYjo0C2qoxiyrrLgrqIjFNVnt13/RGlzGfjNe2@G4WXpZZy37UJqnjeJYLKosRKx2pAPqkdCpEZQsdSOCw8CpmpMgsCMpc5Ax0o4NByqLNA2oO5qquzjQNywijkedFrsVNKrfhljNKtECd4eQhodt6fLM6KM2UU@v5oYxzWSkAKd7ZgknbGC9YT5XcCXkxcNAmN/rAZ2CqGTfDDcaxTKmUnHu0zuq23tyQEsif0GBJCSNw), however system is creating an additional `sh` process and waits for its termination